# Sum column total (only once per duplicate row data)

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have the following `orders` table, and I'm retrieving all `failed` orders.

```
+----+------------------+-------+--------+
| id | email            | total | status |
+----+------------------+-------+--------+
| 1  | john@example.com | 39.99 | failed |
|----|------------------|-------|--------+
| 2  | john@example.com | 39.99 | failed |
|----|------------------|-------|--------+
| 3  | pete@example.com | 19.99 | failed |
+----+------------------+-------+--------+
```

I need to get the total number of failed orders, as well as their summed total, but only once per duplicate row (row is considered a duplicate when same `email` and `total` are the same)

Currently I have a very simple query which gets the total of all `failed` orders. I'm not sure how to go about modifying it to return the desired data (I've tried messing around with `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` to no avail.)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`, SUM(`total`) AS `grand_total` FROM `orders` WHERE `status` = 'failed';
```

Which returns:

```
+-------+-------------+
| count | grand_total |
+-------+-------------+
|   3   |   99.97     |
+-------+-------------+
```

The result I'd like to return is:

```
+-------+-------------+
| count | grand_total |
+-------+-------------+
|   2   |    59.98    |
+-------+-------------+
```

(the second row would be omitted from the result as the `email` and `total` have the same values as those in the first row)

Is it possible to retrieve this data in a single query?

Comment: What if one row of a duplicate fails and the other does not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to do the `distinct` or `group by` in a subquery:

```
select count(*), sum(total)
from (select distinct email, total
      from orders
      where status = 'failed'
     ) et;
```

Comment: Ah thank you (again), I can't believe I didn't think of that ;(

Comment: But you have subquery, is it better than one query?

Comment: @VladimirKovpak . . . I can't think of a realist way of returning what the OP wants without a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email, total)
FROM orders WHERE status = 'failed'
;
```

In this case we build pseudo-unique key from email and total, and count only unique occurrences...
It should work...

Comment: MySQL allows multiple columns for `count(distinct)`, so you can use `count(distinct email, total)`.

Comment: Thank you Gordon so much! You are right! I check it - it works!

Comment: Should i left both examples? or just COUNT(DISTINCT email, total)? what you think?

Comment: The multiple argument approach is better.  For instance, the multi argument method handles `NULL` values correctly.